# Unknown directive type "http:get"

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I use Sphinx with sphinxcontrib-httpdomain for writing documentation for APIs.

But when I did it last time (*make html*) I got an error:

```
reading sources... [100%] administrator_operations                                                                      
/path/to/my/project: ERROR: Unknown directive type "http:get".
```

end after message my reStructuredText.

I have all components:

```
$ pip search sphinxcontrib-httpdomain
sphinxcontrib-httpdomain  - Sphinx domain for HTTP APIs
INSTALLED: 1.1.8 (latest)
```

Comment: Is "sphinxcontrib.httpdomain" included in the [extensions](http://sphinx-doc.org/config.html#confval-extensions) configuration variable in conf.py?

Comment: Could you add the snippet of restructured text where it goes wrong? Perhaps there's a typo in there.

Answer (score 0):

As @mzjn advised I added `sphinxcontrib.httpdomain` in extensions in [conf.py](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-extensions):

```
extensions = [
    '...',
    'sphinxcontrib.httpdomain',
]
```